# Use reduce() method to find a skipped number in an array of consecutive numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, numbers, reduce

I'm trying to use the `reduce()` method to find one skipped (missing) number in an array of (sometimes almost) consecutive numbers. Only one number will be missing at most.
This is my codepen: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/zBrRVd

For example,
`findMissing([1,2,3,5])` should return 4 

`findMissing([1,2,3,4])` should return `undefined` 

`findMissing([2,3,4,6])` should return 5

`findMissing([2,4,5,6])` should return 3

The code that I developed seems to work fine if there is indeed a number that was skipped. But it returns an undesired value if all numbers are present. Would you know how to fix it?

**My JS code:**

```
function findMissing(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
    if (curr - prev !== 1) {
      return curr - 1;
    }
  });
}


// This should return 4, and it indeed returns 4
console.log(   findMissing([1,2,3,5])   );


// This should return 'undefined', but it returns 3
console.log(   findMissing([1,2,3,4])   );


// This should return 5, and it indeed returns 5
console.log(   findMissing([2,3,4,6])   );
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Based on the answers below, the following code delivers the desired outcome using the `reduce()` method:

```
// ****SOLUTION:****
function findMissing2(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, array) {
    if (curr === index + array[0]) {
      return prev;
    } else {
      return index + array[0]++;
    }
  }, void 0);
}

console.log(   findMissing2([1,2,3,4])   ); // Undefined
console.log(   findMissing2([1,2,3,5])   ); // 4
console.log(   findMissing3([2,3,4,6])   ); // 5
console.log(   findMissing2([2,3,4,5])   ); // Undefined
console.log(   findMissing2([2,4,5,6])   ); // 3
```

Comment: Since you have a 'base case' you could do it(with more efficiency I think) with recursivity(or even with a while loop).

Comment: what should happen, if more than one number is missing, like `[1, 4]` or `[1, 3, 5]`?

Comment: There is assurance in this task that it will only be 1 number missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this job as follows;

```js
var a1 = [1,2,3,5],
    a2 = [2,3,4,5],
    a3 = [2,4,5,6],
  res1 = a1.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c == i+a[0] ? p : i + a[0]++, void 0),
  res2 = a2.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c == i+a[0] ? p : i + a[0]++, void 0),
  res3 = a3.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c == i+a[0] ? p : i + a[0]++, void 0);
console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
console.log(res3);
```

Note: `void 0` is a very safe `undefined` value in JS. The above code will mutate the tested array. You might prefer to call like `a1.slice().reduce...` if you want to keep the tested array as it is.

Comment: Redu, I'm doing further tests and actually the solution does not work for arrays not starting at 1. For example: `findMissing([2,4,5,6,7])`  Would you know how to fix it? Is it possible using the `reduce()` method?

Comment: @Piotr Berebecki could you please check now?

Comment: You are a true JS ninja! What do those two plus symbols do in this context? I was only aware of using them for increments (e.g. `i++`)

Comment: @Piotr Berebecki Thanks Piotr but it's pretty basic but just looks a little cryptic. I have corrected the code into a more readable form. It actually, as you say, increments `a[0]` if it meets an irregularity in the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your reduce closure/callback function needs to return the value to be used as the next `prev` in the next iteration.

Because of this, in the second example, the first iteration returns `undefined`, as it does not enter the `if` block. The second iteration is passed the parameters of `undefined, 3`, where `undefined - 3 !== 1` so it returns 2.

This propagates the way up your iterations, until it returns 3.

As such, I'm struggling to think of a way your `reduce` function could be adapted to correct this.

Perhaps using a simple `for` loop might be a bit more robust?

```
function findMissing(arr) {
   for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i] - arr[i-1] !== 1) {
           return arr[i]-1;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The docs for the `reduce()` method on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce say that 'If no initialValue is provided, then previousValue will be equal to the first value in the array and currentValue will be equal to the second.' so I assumed that in the first loop `prev` will equal to 1 and `curr` will equal to 2. Do you think that isn't the case?

Comment: Ah, a typo. But you are correct, in the first loop, it will be `1, 2`. But the return value from the first loop will be `undefined`, so in the second loop it will have the parameters `undefined, 3`. I will modify my answer to correct the typo.

Comment: Please restore your answer you deleted recently. Nobody can order you so. Your answer is way better and less confusing for the OP

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reduce you should use `for` loop here

```js
function findMissing(arr) {
  var r = [];
  for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[arr.length - 1]; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(i) == -1) r.push(i);
  }
  return r;
}


console.log(findMissing([1, 2, 3, 5]));
console.log(findMissing([1, 3, 6]));
console.log(findMissing([10, 13, 16]));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, if you are looking for efficiency you could do it with recursion:

```
function findMissing(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) return;
    if(arr[1] - arr[0] !== 1){
        return arr[0];
    }
    else{
        return findMissing(arr.slice(1,arr.length));
    }
}
```

Or even with a while loop:

```
function findMissing(arr) {
    var i = 0;
    while (arr[i+1] - arr[i] === 1) {
        i++;
    }
    if (i < arr.length-1) return arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var findMissing = function (list) {  
           var expected_sum = (list[0] + list[list.length - 1]) * (list.length + 1) / 2;
           var sum = list.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
           return expected_sum - sum;
         }
          
          console.log(findMissing([-5,-1,1,3,5,7,9,11]))
```